# Overriding imported CSS styles in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sweetalert2

I am pulling in SweetAlert2 into Vuejs into my app using

```
import VueSweetAlert from 'vue-sweetalert';
Vue.use(VueSweetAlert);
```

This imports the whole package from the node_models folder. I now want to override SweetAlert2's sass files so I have copied and imported them into my local sass directories.

However they don't override the node_modules css. How can I configure Vuejs to import and use a plugin but to override the native styling with the copied styles that are in my project without having to put `!important` all over them?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that it's not possible to extend styles because of the `vue-sweetalert` imports already generates css styles, not scss: https://github.com/lishengzxc/vue-sweetalert/blob/master/src/vue-sweetalert.js#L2

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your custom css files after the `VueSweetAlert` import like:

```
import VueSweetAlert from 'vue-sweetalert';
import '<path-to-your-custom-css>.css';
```

This seems like a hack or workaround, but it should override the defined css rules in `vue-sweetalert`.